# Signing out of Google+ using JS

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to put a Google+ login button on my site. The button works perfectly. I have a Sign Out button also. I hide the sign in button when the user logs in.My code is here:

```
<span id="signinButton">
    <span
        class="g-signin"
        data-callback="signinCallback"
        data-clientid="******************"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
    </span>
</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="revokeButton" onclick="gapi.auth.signOut()">Sign Out</button>

<script>
    function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
            document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            console.log("User successfully logged in!!");
        } else {
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    function disconnectUser(access_token) {
        var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
                access_token;

        // Perform an asynchronous GET request.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: revokeUrl,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(nullResponse) {
                document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: display');
                // The response is always undefined.
                console.log("Success in logging out!");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                // Handle the error
                console.log(e);
                // You could point users to manually disconnect if unsuccessful
                // https://plus.google.com/apps
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is when I use gapi.auth.signOut() to sign out... it logs me out, but logs in the same user again to Google+ on refresh. How do I allow other people to login to my site. How do I completely logout people from  Google. I am new to Javascript...an example would help.

Comment: Are you calling the signin function on page load?

Comment: No..only when the signinButton is clicked..when I click the button...a dialog appears and dissappears...which means the previous user was logged  in.

Comment: My first question is this: do you intend to make your site a proxy for the user to log in and out of google+, or do you intend to use google+ as a way of authorizing account creation for access to your site?  If I went to someSite.com, and logged in with google+, then logged out of that site, I wouldn't expect to actually be logged out of my google+ account.  It may be that google is enforcing a rule such that third party sites cannot log users out of google+.

Comment: Well there has to be something trying to sign in the user after refreshing. If you have anymore Google-API javascript on your page, please add it to your question.

Comment: True...I use it as a way of accessing my site. Then how do I allow other users to login.

Comment: @MallikKumar Do you have a database backing your site that includes some persistence of verified users?  You can use Google+ Platform API to prefill and insert a new user into that database, and to authenticate them when they come back, but the "login/logout" logic should be local to your site/app, based upon that DB entry.

Comment: I don't have a DB... is logging into Google+ so complicated...I have posted some code I removed before...I tried the last script and got a successful console.log. But the user still gets logged in anyway...

Comment: Well, I guess my next question would be then why are they logging in at all if you're not capturing & saving data to associate with unique visitors to your site?  It seems to me, perhaps naively, like this is gating users for no reason.  Is the intention to grant g+ users to special content that isn't otherwise available?

Comment: True... I am handling  this module  without knowing its true purpose..but my problem remains...how to logout users out of Google+ and login a new user.

Comment: Keep in mind, you're not "logging into Google+", you're "using Google+ to allow a user to log into my site".  Your site should have its own record of who can and can't log in, hence a DB.  Google won't implicitly save that information for you, so far as I know.  Alternatively, you could just remove the Google+ login logic, since it's currently superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as I figured out is simple. The first time the user logs in, he is not logged into my site . So obviously the user has to log in. The next time the page refreshes...Google+ checks if the user is already logged into any of Google services such as gmail etc.. and keeps the user logged in if the answer is true. To check whether this works...log out of any of your Google service(gmail etc) and try logging in with Google+. It will ask for credentials. So once the user logs in to Google+, he/she need not keep signing in every time.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is more of a joke but why don't you try the hacky method of loging out the user from his google account by adding hidden iframe to the body with `src` of `https://accounts.google.com/Logout`?

It will refuse to display because of the X-Frame-Options set to DENY but will actually log you out.

One-liner with jquery:

```
$('<iframe style="display: none" src="https://accounts.google.com/Logout"></iframe>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: It is not recommended to rely on a hacky side-effect. This could stop working at anytime leaving sites that build off it broken.

Comment: Of course not. Mentioned it as a joke, not as a solution. OP should know all his options. Not just the correct ones ;)